# What would cause PHP variables to be rewritten by the server?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, redhat

I was given a VM at my company to install web software on. But I came across a rather bizarre issue where PHP variables would be overwritten (rewritten) by the server if they matched a specific pattern. What could rewrite PHP variables like this?

The following is as an entire standalone script.

```
<?php
$foo = 'b.domain.com';
echo $foo; // 'dev01.sandbox.b.domain.com'

$bar = 'dev01.sandbox.domain.com';
echo $bar; // 'dev01.sandbox.sandbox.domain.com'

$var = 'b.domainfoo.com';
echo $var; // 'b.domainfoo.com' (not overwritten because it didn't match whatever RegEx has been set)
?>
```

Essentially any variable which contains a subdomain and matches on the domain name would be rewritten. This isn't something mod_rewrite would be able to touch, so it has to be something at the server level that is parsing out PHP and rewriting a string if it matches a RegEx.

Comment: i would search "sandbox" on every file on the server.

Comment: I grep-ed for sandbox in /etc already.

Comment: If you phpinfo() this machine, do you see something not normal?

Comment: What does var_dump on those variables produce?

Comment: vm, you could just reinstall php from source, but this is an interesting one :-)

Comment: Do you have a typo on `foo = 'b.domain.com';`?  Should it have a dollar sign at the start?

Comment: You cannot assign to constant `foo`... It's probably issue when copy pasting, but I've wanted to mention it anyways.

Comment: Typo when editing in SO, fixed.

Comment: When providing tech support I have quite often found problems when people rewrote, or stripped out their domain stuff. Often the problem is actually in what they removed, but they didn't realize it. Adjusting the debugging output makes it impossible to debug. -- Additionally, I'd like to know what dev01.b.domain.com displays to see if we can find the pattern. The two results you shared are inconsistent.

Comment: @DustinGraham I know what you're talking about, but that is not the case here because the matching is done on the domain itself. I cannot show you what the domain actually points to because it's on the internal network. (Trust me, it wouldn't help anyway). To make it simple, the matching is `([a-zA-Z\.]+).<domain>` (or similar) and it rewrites it as: `<host>.sandbox.(match).<domain>`. However, that is not the question. The question being asked here is what is capable of rewriting/overwriting PHP variables on output? We discovered the answer and I'll post it when I return to the office.

Comment: Who setup the environment? Have you asked them?

Comment: as thetaiko said, what does var_dump on the variables produce? check if the length in the var_dump output is correct. This would tell you if it is happening in php (as in the value in the variable is being changed) or if the output is being buffered and edited afterwards by either an append script or apache. Also, check phpinfo() for an append script running that might edit the output buffer.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn var_dump produces the same value as echo. But the string length isn't correct. So you're correct in that regard because it is being edited by apache using the `PerlOutputFilterHandler`. There was/is no indication in phpinfo() for append or filter being run on the output. (Used multiple search terms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output overwriting is possible within Apache by using mod_perl: PerlOutputFilterHandler.

The following could be added to an apache.conf to set the output filter:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html?|php|xml|css)$">
    PerlSetVar Filter On
    PerlHandler MyApache2::FilterDomain
    PerlOutputFilterHandler MyApache2::FilterDomain
</FilesMatch>
```

Example filter handler code:

```
#file:MyApache2/FilterDomain.pm
#--------------------------------
package MyApache2::FilterDomain;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Apache2::Filter();
use Apache2::RequestRec();
use APR::Table();

use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(OK);

use constant BUFF_LEN => 1024;

sub handler {
    my $f = shift;
    my @hostname = split(/\./, $f->r->hostname);
    my $new_hostname = $hostname[0].".".$hostname[1];

    unless ($f->ctx) {
        $f->r->headers_out->unset('Content-Length');
        $f->ctx(1);
    }

    while ($f->read(my $buffer, BUFF_LEN)) {
        $buffer =~ s/([a-z0-9]+)+\.domain\./$new_hostname\.$1.domain\./g;   
        $f->print($buffer);
    }

    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}
1;
```

More on Apache mod_perl filters can be found here: [mod_perl: Input and Output Filters](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/filters.html)